# Pila LEMP en docker

Tags: php, apache, docker, nginx, lamp

presento mi problema, el Dockerfile lo tengo hecho y creado, pero no se como ni porque siempre sale **Welcome to nginx!**, algo me tiene que faltar y no se que es, muestro primero como tengo hecho la estructura:

[image: lemp tree]

En cada carpeta como mysql y nginx tengo el Dockerfile, de momento solo he creado en nginx porque luego me ocuparé de hacer la conexión con la base de datos.

Os muestro el **Dockerfile**:

```
    # Usamos de base la imagen de Nginx oficial
    FROM nginx:latest

    # Actualizamos e instalamos los programas necesarios
    RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y nginx && \
    apt-get install -y ufw && \
    apt-get install -y openssh-server && \
    apt-get install -y php7.4-fpm php-mysql

    # COPIAMOS LOS ARCHIVOS DE CONFIG
    # Añadimos OpenSSH a ufw
    COPY ./files/openssh-server /etc/ufw/applications.d/openssh-server
    # Creamos donde vamos a tener la página web
    COPY ./files/proyecto_educados /var/www/proyecto_educados
    # Creamos el fichero de configuración
    COPY ./files/proyecto_educadosCONF /etc/nginx/sites-available/proyecto_educados

    # Creamos el fichero para hacer los enlaces
    RUN mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

    # Creamos enlaces entre ficheros
    RUN if [ ! -e /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/proyecto_educados ]; then \
    ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/proyecto_educados /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/; \
    fi

    # Eliminamos el enlace simbólico default
    RUN rm -r /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

    # Damos permisos
    RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/proyecto_educados
    RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/proyecto_educados

    # Exponemos el puerto que usará
    EXPOSE 80
```

Yo como véis uso desde una imagen ya creada, mi pagina web es proyecto_educados, en el segundo copy es donde se supone que debería de ir esa carpeta. Si compruebo el funcionamiento en forma de servicio sin docker, si funciona.

Cualquier ayuda es agradecida, muchas gracias de antemano.